# Blog monthly archive block - list of posts grouped by year then month

Tags: views, theming, blocks, nodes

See the implementation on this guy's blog: http://deglos.com/blog

```
YEAR
-- Month
-- Month
YEAR
-- Month
-- Month
```

Anyone know how this was accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

It's normally done using Views and a good tutorial on the process has been explained by Chris Shattuck on his blog - see [How to create a monthly archive block for a Drupal blog with Views](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-create-monthly-archive-block-drupal-blog-views)

A little sleuthing on how the blog you mention was generated leads me to believe that the author wrote the [wp_blog module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wp_blog) on Drupal.org which provides a view that ultimately generates the year -> month -> post hierarchy.  You can see an exported view for the blog archive block here: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/wp_blog/tree/views/wp_blog.view?id=47246da29d176c028a749632807d207dfe0461e1

Comment: Hey George, yeah we've already achieved the monthly archive block so that part is done. The problem we want is to have Year headings to group those Monthly archives together. In fact, the year doesn't even need to link, and can just be text, but we have not been able to achieve this look through views.

Comment: @AlexKatayama were you able to solve this?  I am in the same boat right now!

Comment: For D8 see this answer - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/275848/view-of-blog-posts-grouped-by-year